Problem with web scraping with beautifulsoup
The problem is that the data appears in only one column and is not distributed among the rest of the columns (an image has been attached).
Knowing the seventh step, I used the zip longest method and did unpacking. I do not know exactly where the problem is.
The code :
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

job_title = []
company_name = []
location_name = []
skills = []



#2 use requests to fetch the url
result = requests.get ("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=programmer&a=hpb")

#3 save page content/markup
src = result.content

#4 create soup object to parse content
soup = BeautifulSoup (src, "lxml")

#5 find the elements containing info we need 
#-- job titles, job skills, company names, location names 

job_titles = soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"css-m604qf"})
company_names = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"css-17s97q8"})
locations_names = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"css-5wys0k"})
job_skills = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"css-y4udm8"})

#6 loop over returned lists to extract needed info other lists

for i in range(len(job_titles)):
    job_title.append(job_titles[i].text)
    company_name.append(company_names[i].text)
    location_name.append(locations_names[i].text)
    skills.append(job_skills[i].text)

#7 create csv file and fill it with values
file_list = [job_title, company_name, location_name, skills]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)

with open("job.csv", "w" ) as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(["job title", "company name", "location", "skills"])
    wr.writerows(exported)

I used unpacking and zip_longest so that each title appears in a column and the details appear in rows consistent with it

First of all, you made a good effort and nearly got there on your own !!
Using exactly the code that you have up to the point #7 in the question i do everything the same.

Then i push the data into a pandas DataFrame.

From there it is easy to create a CSV file (in fact, it is easier to write a CSV file this way).


So this works perfectly well:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'job_title':job_title,
    'company_name':company_name,
    'location_name':location_name,
    'skills':skills
    }
)

df.to_csv('some_file_name.csv')

Also, i can cleanly see the data in the dataframe which looks like this:

And here is the actual CSV:


Unfortunately, the problem still exists
https://imgur.com/a/3xdasfd

@Lpython,  this completely works.  perhaps you are opening the CSV file without delimiters in excel which would cause the screenshot that was attached.

@Lpython,   i added the actual CSV (image) that one can see to the answer for completeness. I viewed the CSV file in VScode using rainbowCSV.
